# How to select <option> item by the "value" attribute in <select> drop-down list?

Tags: delphi, dom, twebbrowser

In my Delphi application I'm using a `TWebBrowser` control, where I have loaded an HTML document, containing a `<select>` element (drop down list) with a few `<option>` items (drop down list items). Let's say, I have the following HTML document loaded in my web browser:

```
<html>
<body>
  <select id="ComboBox">
    <option value="firstvalue">First Value</option>
    <option value="secondvalue">Second Value</option>
    <option value="thirdvalue">Third Value</option>
  </select>  
</body>
</html>
```

How can I programatically select e.g. the `<option>`, whose `value` attribute is `thirdvalue` ? Or in other words, how can I programatically select the third item in this drop down list, when I know only that this item's `value` attribute is `thirdvalue` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`IHTMLSelectElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface with its [`selectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property for instance. As a showcase I've made the following function.

### SelectOptionByValue function

The following function tries to find, and select (if found) an `<option>` (a drop down list item) of a given `value` attribute value in a specified `<select>` element (drop down list). If no `<option>` is found, the current drop down list selection is cleared (no item is selected).

***Parameters:***

- ADocument - the interface to an input HTML document
- AElementID - ID of a `<select>` element (element ID of a drop down list)
- AOptionValue - searched `<option>` element value (value of a drop down list item)

***Return value:***

If the `<option>` with a given `value` is successfully found (and selected), the return value is the index of that option in a specified drop down list, -1 otherwise.

***Source code:***

```
function SelectOptionByValue(const ADocument: IDispatch; const AElementID,
  AOptionValue: WideString): Integer;
var
  HTMLDocument: IHTMLDocument3;
  HTMLElement: IHTMLSelectElement;

  function IndexOfValue(const AHTMLElement: IHTMLSelectElement;
    const AValue: WideString): Integer;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    Result := -1;
    for I := 0 to AHTMLElement.length - 1 do
      if (AHTMLElement.item(I, I) as IHTMLOptionElement).value = AValue then
      begin
        Result := I;
        Break;
      end;
  end;

begin
  Result := -1;
  if Supports(ADocument, IID_IHTMLDocument3, HTMLDocument) then
  begin
    if Supports(HTMLDocument.getElementById(AElementID), IID_IHTMLSelectElement,
      HTMLElement) then
    begin
      Result := IndexOfValue(HTMLElement, AOptionValue);
      HTMLElement.selectedIndex := Result;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

***Example usage:***

To select the item with `thirdvalue` value in drop down list from the HTML document from the question it's possible to use this code (assuming in the `WebBrowser1` component here is loaded that document):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := SelectOptionByValue(WebBrowser1.Document, 'ComboBox', 'thirdvalue');

  if Index <> -1 then
    ShowMessage('Option was found and selected on index: ' + IntToStr(Index))
  else
    ShowMessage('Option was not found or the function failed (probably due to ' +
      'invalid input document)!');
end;
```

Example HTML document from the question:

```
<html>
<body>
  <select id="ComboBox">
    <option value="firstvalue">First Value</option>
    <option value="secondvalue">Second Value</option>
    <option value="thirdvalue">Third Value</option>
  </select>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [+1] Since you included `if Supports`, HTMLElement might be other than `IHTMLSelectElement` so I would use: `if Supports(HTMLDocument.getElementById('ComboBox'), IID_IHTMLSelectElement, HTMLElement) then...`. just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: @kobik, interesting, I haven't been notified about this comment (even if I'm the post owner). Of course, that will be much better!