# Delphi Webbrowser select combobox

Tags: delphi, combobox, browser

In my Delphi application I'm using a TWebBrowser control, where I have loaded an HTML document, containing a  element (drop down list) with a few  items (drop down list items). Let's say, I have the following HTML document loaded in my web browser:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <select id="kurumTipi" class="fixedLength currencySel fullLength type:(json) onSuccess:(fillMultiple) param:(kurumAdi) emptyItem:(true) emptyItemValue:(false) emptyName:(Lütfen seçin.)" name="kurumTipi" jquery15207697552179207936="233" receivedfocus="true"> 
   <option value="">Lütfen seçin.</option> 
   <option value="FTRA±DGAZ±Doğalgaz±CHECKSUM_d56898e67b99aed5565c0f3500017f0c">Doğalgaz</option> 
   <option selected="" value="FTRA±ELKT±Elektrik±CHECKSUM_6940c364baaadf475a87ea30de904c5d">Elektrik</option>
   <option value="FTRA±NOTR±Noter Odası Ödemeleri±CHECKSUM_deca6291b6d9b3b117a4342c0887d260">Noter Odası Ödemeleri</option>
   <option value="FTRA±OZFR±Sigorta ve Özel Firma Ödemeleri±CHECKSUM_957a48160b10d7b9d514ebbcc297fe1b">Sigorta ve Özel Firma Ödemeleri</option>
   <option value="FTRA±SUOD±Su±CHECKSUM_bd6be042ec748f88cbb60e697ca1eb6d">Su</option>
   <option value="FTRA±TKKR±Tüketici Finansmanı±CHECKSUM_14bd912b2ea7a461502e330e8314b81a">Tüketici Finansmanı</option>
   <option value="FTRA±TLKM±Telekomünikasyon±CHECKSUM_4e222b9f4c055689b5f25e174d768b18">Telekomünikasyon</option>
   <option value="FTRA±UAID±Üyelik Aidatı±CHECKSUM_dddca41735a51150d8c087b0fcc8438c">Üyelik Aidatı</option>
   </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

How do you select the combobox and Elektrik ?

I have no problem with the local server can change. But on the Web does not change the selected combobox is empty.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the note from your question update. Using the very same document in a web browser control will do the same regardless where the page was loaded from.

Comment: I've tried : localhost and internet with tWebBrowser. The combobox is shown and `Elektrik` is selected. I can not really understand your question.

Comment: This file has the web page. Is an interactive combobox. Electricity is selected, the second combobox is active                      http://rapidshare.com/files/1610842534/WebFile.rar

Comment: Are you asking how to focus the combobox?

Comment: WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('kurumtipi').selectedindex:=2;                                                                  Elektrik choose a combobox on the bottom with the code, but do not actively

Comment: WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('kurumtipi').value:='FTRA±ELKT±Elektrik±CHECKSUM_6940c364baaadf475a87ea30de904c5d';          This code does not fulfill the selection of the combobox

Comment: Voted to close as *not a real question*. If you want to select an item use the code in the duplicate, or your previous comment. If you also want to activate/focus the combobox, you can *additionally* use `(HTMLDocument.getElementById('kurumTipi') as IHTMLElement2).focus;` if you chose the DOM way, or `WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('kurumTipi').Focus;` if you chose automation. If you want to do something else comment in Turkish and I'll translate.

Comment: Upload it somewhere else or grant permissions for all: *"Download permission denied by uploader. (0b67c2f5)"*

Comment: @Bora - Despite various script errors here (with Ie8), selecting an item (with f.i. 'selectedindex') and focusing the combobox (with 'focus') works fine here.

Comment: (selectedindex)but on the other combobox, the selection is not active. What is the code you are trying?

Comment: procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if combobox1.text = 'Elektrik' then
  webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('kurumtipi').selectedindex:=2;
end;

Comment: Kurum_tipi selected in this way. But it is not active Kurum_

Comment: @Bora - Select the item and then activate the combobox. You need two statements, I already told it. First statement `webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('kurumtipi').selectedindex:=2`, second statement: `WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('kurumTipi').Focus`. Two statements, not one.

Comment: Where is my fault?                                                        begin
  if combobox1.text = 'Elektrik' then
  webbrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('kurumtipi').selectedindex:=2;
 WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('kurumTipi').Focus;
end;

Comment: @Bora - No faults there. It's the exact same code that works here on the download you've provided. Copy/pasted your comment here once more to be sure, it works here. Maybe it works because of the script errors, I have no idea..

Comment: one minute add the project look?

Comment: @Bora, I've made an update to [the linked question answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12875791/960757). Maybe you might try to adopt that function (I'm just not a big fan of `OleObject` access to document) for your case. It only selects the option in drop down list (if found), it doesn't focus the control (which seems to be also your intention).

Comment: @Bora, If I get you right, it's not a duplicate. My guess is that you want to select an item in drop down list by the *"item text"*. And, except that also focus that drop down list control. Do you want to select the item by its text ? E.g. select the 8th item when you know it contains *"Telekomünikasyon"* ? And then focus that drop down list control ?

Comment: "Here's all my code, I'm trying to select this element, what am I doing wrong?" is what this question boils down to. Not an acceptable format here on StackOverflow. If the real question is revealed in the comments, then perhaps you should think about what people need to know to be able to answer your question before you ask it. Referencing to code on third-party sites is always frowned upon here because 5 years from now that link may no longer work.

Comment: @TLama Yes item text and I want to choose

Comment: the my file adress http://ul.to/m5ehdp9d

Comment: Try to give a try to [this function](http://pastebin.com/NrPwUGWS). It selects an item in drop down list by text and optionally focuses that drop down list.