# Modify below function to select item from dropdown

Tags: html, delphi, twebbrowser

I have the following Delphi code to fill form on a TWebBrowser:

```
procedure SetFieldValue(theForm: IHTMLFormElement; const fieldName: string; const newValue: string);
   var
     field: IHTMLElement;
     inputField: IHTMLInputElement;
     selectField: IHTMLSelectElement;
    textField: IHTMLTextAreaElement;
begin
  field := theForm.Item(fieldName, '') as IHTMLElement;
  if Assigned(field) then
  begin
    if field.tagName = 'INPUT' then
    begin
      inputField := field as IHTMLInputElement;
      // Make the change below to catch checks and radios.
      if (inputField.type_ = 'checkbox') or (inputField.type_ = 'radio') then
      begin
        if newValue = 'Y' then
          inputField.checked := True
        else
          inputField.checked := False;
      end
      else
        inputField.value := newValue;
    end
    else if field.tagName = 'SELECT' then
    begin
      selectField := field as IHTMLSelectElement;
      selectField.value := newValue;
    end
    else if field.tagName = 'TEXTAREA' then
    begin
      textField := field as IHTMLTextAreaElement;
      textField.value := newValue;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

HTML source looks something like this example:

```
<select name="xosid">
   <option value="" selected>-- choose one --</option>
   <option value="first">This is one</option>
   <option value="second">Another</option>
</select>
```

I would like to modify the above function to be able to select from a dropdown the 'Another' without knowing the value...

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Zsolt

Comment: You mean that you want to select the `<option>` by index, or by its *text* ?

Comment: Here you have [`select <option> by text`](http://pastebin.com/NrPwUGWS), [`select <option> by value`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12875791/960757) and if you simplify the latter, you'll get selection by index.

Comment: I would like to select <option> based on the text. Also value is kinda random. Thanks.

Comment: Then you might be looking for a [`code like this`](http://pastebin.com/SUs8thmy). I've improved that quite unsafe part with `tagName` properties.

Comment: Thanks TLama, Just needed this again, and found your code tiptop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to be able to select from a dropdown the 'Another' without knowing the value

So then by index ? option number 2 (starting with zero) ?

Let's start with [searching for data type in Google](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=IHTMLSelectElement&sourceid=opera)

The 1st link is [MSDN specifications for that datatype in Microsoft Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768872.aspx). To the right you can see [selectedIndex: Integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768871.aspx) property.

So the code would be like

```
else if field.tagName = 'SELECT' then
    begin
      selectField := field as IHTMLSelectElement;
      selectField.selectedIndex := 2;
    end
```

And going back to the Google, the 3rd link to me was the ready [source code example](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2009/08/vybor-elementov-v-select-delphi/#comments) using that property.

Comment: Do not rely on `tagName`, rather use e.g. `var SelectElement: IHTMLSelectElement; begin ... if Supports(field, IID_IHTMLSelectElement, SelectElement) then...`.

Comment: @Tlama - this is to topicstarter rather than me

Answer (score 0):

```
    selectField.value := (selectField.item(selectField.length-1,EmptyParam) as IHTMLOptionElement).value;
```